# Summing Documents using Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Data looks like:

```
{
 "id":1234,
  "quantity":10,
  "price":45
},
{
 "id":"1235",
 "quantity":15,
 "price":85
}
```

What I want as the result is

```
{
 "id":1234,
  "quantity":"10",
  "price":45
},
{
 "id":"1235",
 "quantity":15,
 "price":85
},
{
 "id":"",
 "quantity":25,
 "price":130
}
```

I can get just the third document alone by doing

```
{"$group":{
   "_id":"",
   "quantity":{"$sum":"$quantity"},
   "price":{"$sum":"$price"}
}}
```

But I wanted to see all three documents together. Is this even possible using aggregations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$facet:{
   sum:[
    {"$group":{
       "_id":null,
       "quantity":{"$sum":"$quantity"},
       "price":{"$sum":"$price"}
    }}
    ],
    existing:[
    {"$group":{
       "_id":"$id",
       "quantity":{"$sum":"$quantity"},
       "price":{"$sum":"$price"}
    }}
    ]
    }
},
{
$project:{
     items: { $concatArrays: [ "$sum", "$existing" ] }
    }
},
{
 $unwind:{
     path:"$items",
     preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true
     }
},
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$items"}}

])
```